# AWS GLUE transform for binary files in S3 from Protobuf (Google Protocol Buffers) for AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, protocol-buffers, aws-glue

firstly. I am a bit new to this so apologies if my terms are not correct.

**What we are doing**

We have files already in S3 in a Binary file format (e.g. Google Protocol Buffers) which we would like to run an ETL job to create our Data-Lake of transformed data that that will be accessed using either Amazon Redshift or Amazon Athena. In future we may stream via Kinesis.

**Issue we face**

We are looking at using AWS glue but its list of supported formats is limited (CSV, Json, Parquet, Orc, Avro, Grok) and doesn't provide a 'Custom/other' in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html

**Thoughts**

- Is the a cost-effective way to pre-transform the data in S3 wihtin the Glue job to a Parquet input?
- Is there to extend AWS Glue with our custom binary format
- Maybe we are using the wrong AWS tool?

**Key Considerations**

- Costs i.e. If we had to duplicate all the data in S3 for Glue to work on it versus Streaming in-memory transform somehow!
- Later we hope to stream the data using Kinesis

Any help or experience you may have is greatly appreciated, especially examples or existing use-cases as I don't feel what we are trying to do is out of the ordinary... or is it?

Comment: We've spent a few days looking into this with no success. Kinesis can't keep a long history like Kafka, so we'll transform the data in 2 parts: spark job on the historical data, and same transform in kinesis for future data.